# libata patch to allow disable sata port

Tags: disk, patch, sata, libata

My question is related to the patch introduced in this post [How to tell Linux Kernel > 3.0 to completely ignore a failing disk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102648/how-to-tell-linux-kernel-3-0-to-completely-ignore-a-failing-disk)

If the kernel is patched with this code what is the kernel parameter that need to be set to disable ata:2

Cheers

Fred

Comment: Something like `libata.force=1:disable`. I'm not sure how to map `ata:2` to the correct number, just try some numbers to figure out the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, in the meantime I also found an answer from @Rmano on another thread [link] (http://superuser.com/questions/599333/how-to-disable-kernel-probing-for-drive) "libata.force=2.00:disable". This generally works to disable the port but it seems my problem is slightly different as even with the port disabled I get "ata2 comreset failed (errno=-16)" and "ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient"

Answer (score 1):

An answer from @Rmano on another SuperUser Q&A titled: [How to disable kernel probing for drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/599333/).

```
libata.force=2.00:disable
```