# Broken iSSD on motherboard freezes Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, freeze

I have an Asus UX32VD laptop which has a primary harddrive where the OS is installed and a small iSSD of 24GB on the motherboard which is not used for anything. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 64-bit in dual boot on the harddrive.

Unfortunately the iSSD on the motherboard have failed, and I just get errors when trying to communicate with it. Sometimes when Ubuntu 14.04 boot you can see a bunch of ATA2 comreset errors (errno=-16) and you can't see the drive under disks in the OS.

Due to Asus locking down the bios I can't disable the iSSD completely. The iSSD is causing Ubuntu to randomly freeze and I don't know how to set it to ignore the iSSD completely and remove these freezes. Windows take a couple of minutes to boot when it searches for the iSSD but then gives up and run stable, Ubuntu boots quickly but freezes often instead.

I'm not a very experienced Linux user but need it for development purposes and would greatly appreciate any help to get Ubuntu to ignore the signals from the broken iSSD and hopefully stop the freezes.

Comment: You're trying to find a software solution to a hardware problem...  :(  If the BIOS doesn't allow you to disable the hardware, can you just remove it from the motherboard?

Comment: Hi Fabby, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately the only way I can remove it is to solder it off the motherboard which is a risky operation. :(

Comment: Does the LiveDVD still boot?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 still boots, it's just freezes at random times after boot. Sometimes within a minute sometimes within hours. I got a tip about this:http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102648/how-to-tell-linux-kernel-3-0-to-completely-ignore-a-failing-disk which I will give a shot. Seems tricky for my experience but seems worth a shot.