# Q: How to tell the Linux Kernel to ignore MULTIPLE ata devices?

Tags: linux, kernel, grub, libata

So, there were already questions about ignoring ata devices (like [How to tell Linux Kernel > 3.0 to completely ignore a failing disk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102648/how-to-tell-linux-kernel-3-0-to-completely-ignore-a-failing-disk?s=1|0.1741)) from where I got the info that one has to add something like
    `libata.force=2:disable`
to your kernel argument line.
However, for some, reason, on one of my system's controller cards, there are 2 broken ports which are always probed, but I can't switch the card yet. In the first place, there was only one broken port and I could just use the above solution and it worked just fine. Then, when the other port died, I thought I could just add another one of these, like
    `"... libata.force=2:disable libata.force=4:disable"`
which lead to the result that only port 4, and not port 2 was getting ignored, like if the second argument was kinda overriding the first one.
Then I tried
    `"... libata.force=2:disable,4:disable"`
which also didn't work for me.

Q: How can I make the kernel ignore multiple ata devices?

Comment: Just a hopefully helpful addition: I fogot to explain what it does wrong with the second try. It seems to always disable ata4 and always leave ata2 enabled when trying it like that.

Comment: Another addition with more infos: By looking at the kernel command line after reboot with journalctl, I can confirm that the system recognizes my changes, so it indeed passes to the kernel properly what I add in /etc/default/grub. I tried swapping the numbers, too, so it reads `libata.force=4:disable,2:disable` , but still, it does the same thing as before: leave ata2 on, turn ata4 off.

Comment: Does `libata.force=2:disable,4:disable` turn off ata2, but leave ata4 on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always good to refer to [the kernel parameters documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html).

There we can read, for `libata.force`:

> [LIBATA] Force configurations.  The format is comma
> separated list of "[ID:]VAL" where ID is
> PORT[.DEVICE].  PORT and DEVICE are decimal numbers
> matching port, link or device.

Your ports are 2 and 4, and your `VAL` is `disable`. Thus you're looking for `libata.force=2:disable,4:disable`.

Comment: Thank you, indeed I didn't have a look at these parameters (I didn't even know these docs existed) - but if you look above, that's intuitively what I wrote on the second try, and it strangely still doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @TNW link is 404 now