# Disable bad disk from spamming dmesg/journalctl

Tags: hard-disk

Is it possible to disable disk using command line?
I got spam like this:

```
[2245922.091035] ata3: EH complete
[2245922.150696] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[2245922.150701] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[2245922.150703] ata3.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
[2245922.150704] ata3.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 18
                          res 71/04:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[2245922.150708] ata3.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[2245922.150709] ata3.00: error: { ABRT }
[2245922.151027] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/33
[2245922.151030] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[2245922.151034] ata3: EH complete
[2245922.238686] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[2245922.238692] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[2245922.238696] ata3.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
[2245922.238697] ata3.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 24
                          res 71/04:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[2245922.238701] ata3.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[2245922.238702] ata3.00: error: { ABRT }
[2245922.239043] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/33
[2245922.239047] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[2245922.239053] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#24 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[2245922.239056] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#24 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[2245922.239058] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#24 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[2245922.239060] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#24 CDB: Synchronize Cache(10) 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[2245922.239063] I/O error, dev sdd, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 3
```

the problematic disk not mounted and already removed from `/etc/fstab`

```
sdd             8:48   0 223.6G  0 disk
├─sdd1          8:49   0   1.9G  0 part
├─sdd2          8:50   0     1K  0 part
└─sdd5          8:53   0 221.7G  0 part

# 256GB GALAX SSD
#UUID=48c76170-0392-44ce-a8c6-f790673c8f32 /media/asd/galax250 ext4 noatime,user 0 0
```

haven't reboot since I'm still using the PC. It makes everything a bit laggy tho.

[image: GALAX SSD]

Comment: `libata.force=3:disable` might work as a kernel parameter (should disable ata3), another example https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255890/30851 — not sure about disabling it at runtime though

Comment: there is `delete` https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103742/30851 but it's not quite the same as disabling the ata port

Comment: Ultimately, the only solution is to remove (and optionally replace) the failing disk. I hope you've been making regular backups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line in the `dmesg` snippet indicates there is a failing write operation.

You can try:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/block/sdd/device/delete
```

Because of write caching, the application that sent the data to the disk was already "promised" that the data is as good as written, and the kernel **will absolutely try to keep that promise**. So as long as the disk seems to be available, the kernel will keep trying to write the data. This command tells the kernel to prepare the disk for hot-unplugging. If it works, `/dev/sdd` will vanish, and the kernel may attempt to spin down the disk if possible.

(If anyone knows how to explicitly tell Linux kernel "I order you to **lose any cached write operations** to this disk", feel free to write your own answer or edit it into this one.)