# Linux boot parameter ignored when not placed last

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

I'm using ubuntu 22.04, with linux kernel 5.19.0

My laptop has a dead hard drive, which is very sad, but I can't do much about it.

What I (hope I) can do however, is finding a way to avoid having to endure a full minute of `ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)` at each reboot.

From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104177), I found that I could override this behaviour by adding `libata.force=1:disable` to grub linux boot parameters. When I do it manually at boot time, it works perfectly fine. So I tried to do it by default, by editing this line of /etc/default/grub from: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`, to:    `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=1:disable"`.

When rebooting, the actual command line ends up being: `linux [ *some random stuff* ] quiet splash libata.force=1:disable $vt_handoff` with `$vt_handoff` being appended automatically.

This is where my problem begins: it seems that the parameter I added is ignored when placed in penultimate position like this (one full minute of `COMRESET failed`, etc...). When I move it back in last position, it works as intended. Of course, I don't want to have to do it each time I need to reboot.

So my here's my actual question: is there a way to either:

- Force my boot parameter in last position
- Make it so my boot parameter isn't ignored
- Implement some other (better?) way of doing what I want (I don't know much about the way grub works, I'm just trying some stuff I found)